# Selective deleting of messages from POP3 account via Gmail (or anything else)?

Tags: email, gmail, email-client, pop3

I'm importing emails into **Gmail** via **POP3**. Is there a way to **delete** from the server messages with a certain **keyword in the subject** and **leave** everything else on the server? If not Gmail than is there any other way of doing this? It is not possible to create filters on the original server or to add any scripts / cron jobs... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just found that I have **IMAP** access too, so I installed **Thunderbird** and was able to selectively and permanently delete the messages from the server. Not sure if it is possible with **POP3**...